# i made a php file that links my db to my website

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver

i made this php file to link between my website and my db but wamp server keeps giving me this error that i can't resolve 
thank you for your time.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\wamp\www\New folder\socialnetwork\classes\DB.php on line 14

and this is my php file.

```
<?php
class DB {

        private static function connect() {
                $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=SocialNetwork;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
                $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                return $pdo;
        }

        public static function query($query, $params = array()) {
                $statement = self::connect()->prepare($query);
                $statement->execute($params);

                if (explode(' ', $query)[0] == 'SELECT') {
                $data = $statement->fetchAll();
                return $data;
                }
        }

}
?>
```

Comment: Your php version is lower than php5.4

Comment: which php version you are using?

Comment: my php version is PHP Version :
5.3.4

Comment: That's ancient history. You need to update to 5.6 or 7.0. The version you're using dates from 2009.

Comment: there's an alternate method also.

Comment: so if i update my php this error will be fixed ? thank yoi for your time guys really appreciate it

Comment: Yes it will be fixed.

Comment: Then all you will have to do is fix this code so it does not have to connect to the database each time you run a query. Very bad practice and will slow your system enormously.